# If the interior of the boundary of a set is nonempty, then the interior of that set is empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I was reading the post " [A set which the interior of its boundary is not empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024721/a-set-which-the-interior-of-its-boundary-is-not-empty) ", and I conjectured the following:

> Let $ (X, \tau ) $ be a topological space, and let $A \subseteq X $. If $int(\partial A) \neq \phi $ , then $int(A)= \phi $.

(Here $\phi $ represents the empty set).

How can I prove this?

Comment: What if $X=\mathbb R$ and $A=(0,\infty)\cup\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @bof , thank you. I originally wanted to prove that $cl(int(\partial A)) \subseteq cl(A \cap int(\partial A)) $ . Anyhow, now that I see the conjecture is wrong, what should I do with this post? Should I delete it?

Comment: @bof , would you mind writing an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: Leave it up. Just because a conjecture is false does not mean it should be forgotten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conjecture is false. Let $X$ be the real line with the usual topology, and let $A=(0,\infty)\cup\mathbb Q$. Then $\partial A=(-\infty,0]$, so $\operatorname{int}\partial A=(-\infty,0)\ne\emptyset$, but $\operatorname{int}A=(0,\infty)\ne\emptyset$.